problems with locating a media file when creating a media player with JavaFX
I have an exercise at school where i am trying to create a media player in javafx.
I created a MediaView object in scene builder and i placed it in a BorderPane object. It generated the following code for me in the primary.fxml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>


<BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.guigui.testvideo.PrimaryController">
   <center>
      <MediaView fx:id="mediaview" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>

So far we are all well and good.
Then the exercise tells me to write the following code in the primary controller to have the file terre.mp4 played in the media player.
package com.guigui.testvideo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;


import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class PrimaryController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML private MediaView mediaview;
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
    URL myUrl = PrimaryController.class.getResource("terre.mp4");
    Media media = new Media(myUrl.toExternalForm());
    mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(media);  
    
    mediaview.setMediaPlayer(mediaplayer);
    mediaplayer.play();
    
    }

}

There seems be be no syntax error found by my IDE (NetBeans) but when i run the program i get the following message:
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project TestVideo: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

i debugged it and it looks like the program cant find the file and the URL returned by the getResource method is null. The file terre.mp4 is located in the same directory as the primary controller but i can't seem to get it to work. My teacher has not been able to make it work either and i am at a loss here.
Hopefully we are able to find a solution!
Thanks!
I tried to change the directory of the file and the path to have the file located without success. I tried reading the class URL to see how it works and find out what is not working and i can't find the answer either. I am currently studying programming at school so my experience is limited but i am trying to learn and slowly build my knowledge of programming so that i can work in that field when i graduate.

See also Maven (and similar) standard layouts, illustrated here.

In short, Maven uses the "standard directory layout" by default. Any and all non-*.java files are ignored under src/main/java. Move your MP4 file to under src/main/resources/com/guigui/testvideo/ instead and see if that works.
